# What happens to the thread when reaching 'await' on 'async' method?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, ctp

My question as the title suggest is about  the background of 'async' and 'await'.

Is it true to say that what the current thread reaches 'await' keyword, it goes to "sleep",
and wakes up when the await method is done?

Thanks!

Guy

Comment: While I think this could cause a good discussion, the answer should be as easy as googling `async await`. Indeed, you get this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happens to an `awaiting` thread in C# Async CTP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7032290/what-happens-to-an-awaiting-thread-in-c-sharp-async-ctp)

Answer (score 36):

> Is it true to say that what the current thread reaches 'await' keyword, it goes to "sleep", and wakes up when the await method is done?

No. The whole point of `async` is to *avoid* having threads sleeping when they could be doing other work. Additionally, if the thread running the async method is a UI thread, you *really* don't want it to be sleeping at all - you want it to be available to other events.

When execution reaches an `await` expression, the generated code will check whether the thing you're awaiting is already available. If it is, you can use it and keep going. Otherwise, it will add a *continuation* to the "awaitable" part, *and return immediately*.

The continuation makes sure that the rest of the async method gets run when the awaitable value is ready. Which thread that happens in depends on the context in which you're awaiting - if the async method is running in thread pool threads, the continuation could run on a different thread to the one the method started on... but that shouldn't matter. (The rest of the context will still be propagated.)

Note that it's fine for the async method to return without having completed - because an async method can't return a value directly - it always returns a `Task<T>` (or `Task`, or `void`)... and the task returned by the method will be only be completed when the async method has really reached the end.

Comment: I was going to answer, but I'm too late. :) I think this is a good explanation from MSDN: `An await expression does not block the thread on which it is executing. Instead, it causes the compiler to sign up the rest of the async method as a continuation on the awaited task. Control then returns to the caller of the async method. When the task completes, it invokes its continuation, and execution of the async method resumes where it left off.`

Comment: @BobHorn: I like that apart from the way it implies you'll always be awaiting a task :)

Comment: There are two things going on and confusing me. One is we have a method to call which is an argument to await (returning task) and other is the continuation to the task (rest of the method). So both of these are going to run on the SynchronizationContext or one of them (or both) is (are) given special treatment?

Comment: @BSK: The part that you run first to obtain the awaitable doesn't have any special treatment - it's just an expression that produces a value. Although given that the continuation is only run in a synchronization context if you're already *in* a synchronization context, you can't have the latter without the former. But it's not a matter of it being given special treatment - it's just a matter of what the synchronization context is for the currently executing thread.

Comment: This line in the answer "the task returned by the method will be only be completed when the async method has really reached the end." According to my understanding, the task is finished as soon as the thing which we are awaiting on has finished and the rest of the code in async runs as a callback (as we have ContinueWith() for Task). Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @BSK: You're wrong. The point of the task returned by the method is so that the calling code can tell when the *whole async method* has completed. Why would the calling code care when the first awaitable operation had completed? That's just an implementation detail.

Comment: I think that can introduce a deadlock.Take the example of UI thread calling an async method and we know that the rest of the method after the awaitable needs to be executed on the UI thread (due to the synchronization context) but as you are saying that the calling thread (UI thread here) is only notified when all the code in async finished then how UI thread can come back and execute the code after the awaitable when only awaitable has finished (not all the code finished in async method)?

Comment: @BSK: You need to distinguish between the calling *thread* and the calling *code*. Imagine method A calling async method B, which calls async methods C and D. The task returned from B back to A will only complete when the whole of B has finished, which will presumably only happen when the tasks returned by C and D are complete. Rather than continue here, I suggest you do further research and experimentation, then ask a new question with a concrete example if you're still confused.

Comment: Sure. But I have made a lot of research and still having these type of questions. I think you are right. Its time for new question :)

Answer (score 8):

`async` is only syntactic sugar that allows `await` keyword to be used.

If `async, await` is used in ASP.NET Core, then your request thread will be released to thread pool.

[As Stephen Cleary says:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net)

> Asynchronous request handlers operate differently. When a request
> comes in, ASP.NET takes one of its thread pool threads and assigns it
> to that request. This time the request handler will call that external
> resource asynchronously. This returns the request thread to the thread
> pool until the call to the external resource returns. Figure 3
> illustrates the thread pool with two threads while the request is
> asynchronously waiting for the external resource.

[image]

> The important difference is that the request thread has been returned
> to the thread pool while the asynchronous call is in progress. While
> the thread is in the thread pool, it’s no longer associated with that
> request. This time, when the external resource call returns, ASP.NET
> takes one of its thread pool threads and reassigns it to that request.
> That thread continues processing the request. When the request is
> completed, that thread is again returned to the thread pool. Note that
> with synchronous handlers, the same thread is used for the lifetime of
> the request; with asynchronous handlers, in contrast, different
> threads may be assigned to the same request (at different times).

**For desktop application:**

> `await` releases the current thread, but NOT to the thread pool.
> The UI thread doesn't come from the thread pool. If you run asynchronous method,
> e.g. [`ExecuteScalarAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbcommand.executescalarasync?view=net-6.0) without `async, await` keywords, then this method
> will run asynchronously no matter what. The calling thread won't be
> affected .
>
> Special thanks for nice comments to [Panagiotis Kanavos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos).

E.g. you have a heavy stored procedure and your stored procedure takes 10 minutes to be executed. And if you run this code from C# without `async, await` keywords, then your execution thread will wait your stored procedure for 10 minutes. And this waiting thread will do nothing, it will just wait stored procedure.

However, if `async, await` keyword is used, then your thread will not wait stored procedure. The thread will be eligible to work.

Answer (score 6):

Although this question has already been answered by [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) who is a highly skilled person (and one of my favorites), it is worth reading the contents that I mention below for other readers of this post.

By using an **`async`** keyword on a method, the original asynchronous method creates a **state machine** instance, initializes it with the captured state (including `this` pointer if the method is not static), and then starts the execution by calling `AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<T>.Start` with the state machine instance passed by reference.

As soon as control reaches an **`await`** keyword, the current thread (which can be a .Net thread pool's worker thread), creates a **callback** (as a `delegate`) to execute the rest of the sync code exactly after the `await` keyword (**Continuation**) using the **SynchronizationContext/TaskSheduler**'s APIs (`SynchronizationContext` may not be present in all applications, such as Console Applications or ASP.Net Core Web Applications), the captured `SynchronizationContext` is stored in the state machine as an object, the **IO work** is sent to an **IOCP thread**, and the current thread is then released.

The IOCP thread binds to an **IOCP** (IO Completion Port), opens a connection, and asks it to execute the code that has been waited, and the IOCP sends the execution command to the corresponding device (socket/drive).

Whenever the IO work is finished by the relevant device, a **signal** from the IOCP is returned to the IOCP thread along with the result of the IO work, and then the IOCP thread, based on that captured `SynchronizationContext` determines which thread of thread pool should process the continuation/callback (that was stored in the state machine).

[image]

Also, the following articles can be useful:

1. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/dissecting-the-async-methods-in-c/
2. https://tooslowexception.com/net-asyncawait-in-a-single-picture/
3. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/#what-is-a-synchronizationcontext

Answer (score 3):

No. Current thread actually doesn't go to sleep. The execution continues. This is the whole trick of it. You may have some code that processes data while asynchronous actions are still pending. It means that by the time those async completes your main thread is free to run and process other data.

As for the other part of the question - async just executes on another thread, not the current one. I believe that CLR is responsible for spinning those threads, so that many async actions are allowed at the same time (i.e. you may be retrieving data asynchronously from different web servers at the same time).