# Async method waiting for end?

Tags: c#, async-await

I am rewriting some of my component management to use async start methods. Sadly it looks like a call to an `async` method WITHOUT `await`, still does await the result?

Can anyone enlighten me?

I am calling:

```
public async Task StartAsync() {
    await DoStartProcessingAsync();
}
```

which in itself is calling a slow implementation of `protected abstract Task DoStartProcessingAsync();` - slow because it dome some EF calls, then creates an appdomain etc. - takes "ages".

The actual call is done in the form:

```
x.StartAsync().Forget();
```

with "Forget" being a dummy function just to avoid the "no await" warning:

```
public static void Forget(this Task task) {
}
```

Sadly, this sequence - is waiting for the slow `DoStartAsync` method to complete, and I see no reason for that. I am quite old in C#, but quite new to `async/await` and I was under the impression that, unless I await for the async task - the method would complete. As such, I expected the call to `StartAsyc().Forget()` to return immediatly. INSTEAD stack trace shows the thread going all the way into the `DoStartProcessingAsync()` method without any async processing happening.

Anyone can enlighten me on my mistake?

Comment: Can you show `DoStartProcessingAsync()`?  Just to make sure it's not only called `Async` but really is awaiting something and not working synchronously.

Comment: I think this is less about async and more about processing in the background ... for example the `async Task Blah() { await Something(); }` should be just the same as just `Something()` - this does not magically make it happen in the background

Comment: `async` methods will run synchronously till it reaches first await. If there is no await, it runs completely synchronously. Can you post the code of `DoStartProcessingAsync`?

Comment: That one is abou 2 pages of code. It is internally working synchronously - mostly because the slowest parts of it have no async method (i.e. creating an appdomain, loading assemblies into it). I could move some of the code to ahve async (there is some EF in there). But generally- the whole sense of that is from the idea that StartAsync starts a task that then in DoStartProcessingAsync is executing, regardless how it is implemented. The component in question has a status - so the call to Start would put it into "starting" and the end of the DoStartProcessing into Running.

Comment: I'm surprised if you don't want to await you are making your `StartAsync` async and inside `await`ing `DoStartProcessingAsync()`. Why don't you just remove those particular keywords then do `var result = x.StartAsync()` and it should just work

Comment: @SriramSakthivel But this is NOT what the warning says. If I take out the Forget it tells me... "Because this call is not awaited, execution of the method will continue BEFORE the called method has finished".

Comment: @CallumLinington In this case the components act as some service. They go Immediately into a starting sate - initialization can take up to a minute before they switch to running. The whole concept is to return fast to the call to start them.

Comment: @TomTom mere presence of `async` keyword doesn't automagically makes a method asynchronous. There needs to be a `await` keyword and the method you're awaiting should also be asynchronous. If you have time consuming parts in the method, then consider calling it in another thread i.e `await Task.Run(()=> DoStartProcessingAsync());`

Comment: If you want a "fire and forget" type call your likely [better of using Tasks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12804036/542251)

Comment: @TomTom That warning means that when the first await point is hit, your method will continue executing. It won't wait for the whole method (all await points) to complete.

Comment: TomTom what @Liam posted is what I'm saying

Comment: So, you mean I should kill StartAsync and push a Task.Run in Start to make sure it goes into a separate thread? will try that. put it up as an answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What your trying to achieve here is a fire and forget type mechanism. So `async`/`await` isn't really what you want. Your not wanting to `await` anything.

[These are designed to free up threads for long running processes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7244279/542251). Right now your returning a `Task` using an `await` and then "forgetting" it. **So why return the `Task` at all?**

Your freeing up the thread for the long running process, but your also queuing a process that ultimately does nothing (this is adding overhead that you could likely do without).

Simply doing this, would probably make more sense:

```
public void StartAsync() {
    Task.Run(() => DoStartProcessingAsync());
}
```

One thing to bear in mind is that your now using a ThreadPool thread not a UI thread (depending on what is actually calling this).

Comment: I have rewritten Start to use return Task.Run(DoStopProcessingAsync); return task - this way the starting method CAN wait for the execution to finish. Works as intended now.

Comment: @Liam: Should use `Task.Run` and not the much more dangerous `Task.Factory.StartNew`.

Comment: @StephenCleary [Task.run is just a wrapper for the Task.Factory.StartNew with a few switches](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29693430/542251). I don't really see why this add's much benefit? I'll add it for completeness but it's horses for courses, surely? It's also only .Net 4.5.

Comment: @Liam: Yes, but those switches are [really, *really* important to get right](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html). And when you don't specify them, they're wrong.

Comment: I don't target .Net 4.5 currently so we don't use this.